# Stuck with Multi-Client Chat Application

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, sockets

I'm trying to make a MultiClient Chat Application in which the chat is implemented in the client window. I've tried server and client code for the same. I've got two problems:
A. I believe the code should work but, server to client connections are just fine but information isn't transferred between clients.
B. I need a way to implement private one-to-one chat in case of more than two clients, I've used a class to store the information of the Socket object returned for each connection being established, but I can't figure out how to implement it.

The ***server code*** is:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class ClientInfo {

Socket socket;
String name;

public ClientInfo(Socket socket, String name) {
    this.socket = socket;
    this.name = name;
}
}

public class server {

private ObjectInputStream input[] = null;
private ObjectOutputStream output[] = null;
private String value = null;
private static ServerSocket server;
private Socket connection = null;

private static int i = -1;

public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        server = new ServerSocket(1500, 100);
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Waiting for connection from client");
            Socket connection = server.accept();
            i++;
            System.out.println("Connection received from " + (i + 1) + " source(s)");
            //System.out.println(i);

            new ClientInfo(connection, "Client no:" + (i + 1));
            innerChat inc = new server().new innerChat(connection);

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error in public static void main! >>>" + e);
    }
}// end of main!!!

class innerChat implements Runnable {

    private Socket connection = null;

    public innerChat(Socket connection) {
        this.connection = connection;
        Thread t;
        t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            output[i] = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            output[i].flush();
            input[i] = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
}
```

And the ***client code*** is

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

 public class ChatappClient {

private static int port = 1500;
JFrame window = new JFrame("Chat");
JButton sendBox = new JButton("Send");
JTextField inputMsg = new JTextField(35);
JTextArea outputMsg = new JTextArea(10, 35);
private ObjectInputStream input;
private ObjectOutputStream output;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ChatappClient c = new ChatappClient();
    c.window.setVisible(true);
    c.window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    c.run();
}

    public ChatappClient() {

    inputMsg.setSize(40, 20);
    sendBox.setSize(5, 10);
    outputMsg.setSize(35, 50);
    inputMsg.setEditable(true);
    outputMsg.setEditable(false);
    window.getContentPane().add(inputMsg, "South");
    window.getContentPane().add(outputMsg, "East");
    window.getContentPane().add(sendBox, "West");
    window.pack();
    sendBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                output.writeObject(inputMsg.getText());
                outputMsg.append("\n" + "Client>>>" + inputMsg.getText());
                output.flush();
            } catch (IOException ie) {
                outputMsg.append("Error encountered! " + ie);
            }
            inputMsg.setText("");
        }
    });
    inputMsg.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                output.writeObject(inputMsg.getText());
                outputMsg.append("\n" + "Client>>>" + inputMsg.getText());
                output.flush();
            } catch (IOException ie) {
                outputMsg.append("Error encountered! " + ie);
            }
            inputMsg.setText("");
        }
    });
}

private void run() throws IOException {
    Socket clientSocket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", port);
    output = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
    output.flush();
    input = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
    outputMsg.append("I/O Success");
    String value = null;
    while (true) {
        try {
            value = (String) input.readObject();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        outputMsg.append(value + "\n");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please have a look at this [example](http://www.dailyfreecode.com/Code/socket-multi-client-chat-server-1252.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks like it could be improved quite a bit. Your main method for instance should have none of that code in it. It should start your Server class, and that's it (and note that class names should begin with an upper case letter as per Java standards which I strongly advise you to follow).

> I'm trying to make a MultiClient Chat Application in which a Server does nothing but listen and create connections.

The Server is going to have to do more than that. It will need to create Clients, it will need to maintain a collection such as an ArrayList of Clients such as an `ArrayList<ChatappClient>` Otherwise how do you expect the Server to connect two Clients together?

I think that in all you're going to need to think the structure and connections of this program out in more depth before starting to write code.

Comment: If you could please explain the changes required a bit more. Thanks.